# WKWebView: jquery datatable CSV export

Tags: jquery, ios, datatables, export-to-csv, wkwebview

In my iOS app I'm using a `WKWebView` to display a jquery datatable with CSV button to export data (a page very similar to https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html). Now, when I tap on CSV button I would handle data to show it at the user, by `QLPreviewController` for example. On iOS Safari browser, when tap on CSV button, another tab is opened with data. In my `WkWebView` nothing happens.

Is there anybody who can help me to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself.
I'm able to handle the tap by `optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?` method of `WKUIDelegate`

EDIT - Added code as requested by @SeriousSam in comment

```
// MARK: - WKUIDelegate

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
       var urlString = navigationAction.request.url
       let lastPathComponent = urlString!.lastPathComponent
       let encodedLastPathComponent = lastPathComponent.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
       urlString?.deleteLastPathComponent()
       let encodedUrl = urlString!.absoluteString+encodedLastPathComponent!
       let jsHandler = "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;xhr.responseType = 'blob';xhr.onload = function() {var recoveredBlob = xhr.response;var reader = new FileReader;reader.onload = function() {var blobAsDataUrl = reader.result;window.location = blobAsDataUrl;};reader.readAsDataURL(recoveredBlob);};xhr.open('GET', '\(encodedUrl)');xhr.setRequestHeader(\"Cache-Control\", \"no-store\");xhr.send();"
       webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsHandler, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    return nil
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
        if (url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("data:")) {
            let splitted = url.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "base64,")
            if splitted.count == 2 {
                if splitted[0].contains("csv") {
                    self.documentName = "export.csv"
                }
                if let data = Data(base64Encoded: splitted[1]), let documentName = self.documentName {
                    let fileName = String(format: "%@.%@", ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString, "\((documentName as NSString).pathExtension)")
                    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                    do {
                        try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomicWrite)
                        // show the CSV document ...
                        decisionHandler(.cancel)
                        return
                    } catch {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Errore", comment: "Error Alert Title"), message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        decisionHandler(.cancel)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet of how you actually handled it?

Comment: @SeriousSam Edited the answer. It's been a while since I wrote the code. Anyway, I hope it works out for you